# Linking sound in 11월 and 12월

Tags: pronunciation, spoken-korean

I am wondering whether Korean people using linking sound when reading the two months as below. With linking sound, I mean the pronunciation is something like those ones inside square brackets. For me, linking sound is natural part of the language when we reading the words fast enough. However, my friend told me that we should read the words separately. Could you share your opinions on this?

Thank you.

> November: 11월 [si-bi-rwol]
>
> December: 12월 [si-bi-wol]

Source: [Talk To Me In Korean](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fhwcdn.libsyn.com%2Fp%2Fd%2F9%2F1%2Fd91244c1bafc3365%2Fttmik-l2l12.pdf%3Fc_id%3D1834103%26expiration%3D1476866633%26hwt%3D30168ba118893b7b4fccd75abd84161c)

Comment: Short answer yes, 십일월 [시비뤌], 십이월 [시비월]

Comment: Captain America - Civil War :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the standard pronunciation rules, 십일월 should be [시비뤌], and 십이월 [시비월].

In IPA, 십일월 /si.pi.lwʌl/, 십이월 /si.pi.wʌl/. In narrow transcription, 십일월 [ɕibiɾwʌl] and 십이월 [ɕibiwʌl]

Answer (score 3):

If you need to really emphasize it's 11월 instead of 12월 (e.g., you're buying airplane tickets over the phone), you could say "십일-월" (with /l/ sound for "일").

However, you wouldn't normally do that in a conversation.

- In a sense, this is similar to how sometimes people read a phone number as 육팔넷 둘둘하나하나 instead of 육팔사 이이일일.